# How do I test a Spring-WS webservice that Requires soapHeaders?

Tags: java, integration-testing, spring-ws

I have a spring-ws (2.0.2) service I have implemented that requires some custom elements in the soap header.  I am trying to use Spring's MockWebServiceClient to generate a valid request to test the dispatcher, marshallers, etc.

The problem I am getting is that the MockWebSerivce only seems to support the Soap Body (the payload).

How can I access the soap request being generated to get the right headers into it?

If there is a better library for doing this other than Spring's MockWebServiceClient, that would be fine too.

Related Links:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101708-MockWebServiceClient-amp-WS-Security
[Add SoapHeader to org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274378/add-soapheader-to-org-springframework-ws-webservicemessage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar problem when I wanted to test spring web service with Security, I ended up using the Spring Interceptors to modify the header before they reach end point, I enabled the interceptors only for testing.

Create an interceptor, I implemented the SmartEndpointInterceptor, You can use the other interceptors if you choose

```
public class ModifySoapHeaderInterceptor implements
    SmartEndpointInterceptor 
{
  //WSConstants.WSSE_NS;
   private static final String DEFAULT_SECURITY_URL = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    private static final String SECURITY_TAG = "Security";
    private static final String SECURITY_PREFIX = "wsse";
    private static final String USER_NAME_TOKEN = "UsernameToken";

    @Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception 
{
      SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage(SaajSoapMessage)messageContext.getRequest());
      SOAPHeader soapHeader = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart()
            .getEnvelope().getHeader();

       //you can modify header's as you choose
       Name headerElement = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart()
            .getEnvelope()
            .createName(SECURITY_TAG, SECURITY_PREFIX, DEFAULT_SECURITY_URL);
       SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader
            .addHeaderElement(headerElement);
    SOAPElement usernameToken = soapHeaderElement.addChildElement(
            USER_NAME_TOKEN, SECURITY_PREFIX);

    SOAPElement userNameElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username",
            SECURITY_PREFIX);
    userNameElement.addTextNode("userid");//you can inject via spring

    SOAPElement passwordElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("Password",
            SECURITY_PREFIX);
    passwordElement.addTextNode("password");
       return true;
    }
}
```

Configure this interceptor in spring context

```
  <sws:interceptors>
     <bean class="prasanna.ws.security.wss4j.ModifySoapHeaderInterceptor"/>
  </sws:interceptors>
```

This will add the necessary security headers to the message before it reaches the end point, You can still use MockWebServiceClient to test your web service.

Comment: nice thanks.  Since I use an alternate context.xml for testing that includes my production one  i could put the interceptor just in that context I assume.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, the `MockWebServiceClient` *sendRequest()* method only sets up the SOAP body with the payload given it. It does not touch the SOAP header.

To set up the SOAP header as well you can create a class that implements the `RequestCreator` interface and sets the SOAP header. Pass an instance of this class to the *sendRequest()* method.

For example:

```java
class SoapActionCreator implements RequestCreator {

    private final Source payload;

    public SoapActionCreator(Source payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    @Override
    public WebServiceMessage createRequest(WebServiceMessageFactory webServiceMessageFactory)
            throws IOException {
        WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage =
                new PayloadMessageCreator(payload).createMessage(webServiceMessageFactory);

        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
        SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        // Add an Action element to the SOAP header
        StringSource headerSource = new StringSource(
                "<wsa:Action xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">https://example.com/foo/bar</wsa:Action>");
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());

        return webServiceMessage;
    }
```

}

Then use `SoapActionCreator` like this:

```
    SoapActionCreator soapActionCreator = new SoapActionCreator(requestPayload);
    mockClient.sendRequest(soapActionCreator).
            andExpect(payload(responsePayload));
```

where `requestPayload` is the SOAP request body and `responsePayload` is the entire SOAP response (header and body).

Answer (score 0):

I did find the smock library which does what I really wanted: just takes a text file with the whole request in it.

http://code.google.com/p/smock/wiki/SpringWs

It supports the same request and response matchers as the spring provided stuff. It also keeps my tests very self contained.  (Rather than a whole new class that would only be used in my test cases.)