# Add custom Http header to SOAP request with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, jaxb, azure-api-management

I am trying to call a SOAP API which is on the Azure API Manager. In order to call the API I need to add the API subscription code to the header of the request. I cannot figure out how to add an HTTP header to the SOAP request and keep getting a 401 response.

**SoapConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class SoapConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.soap.api.transunion.consumer");
        return marshaller;
    }
    
}
```

**Service.java**

```java
@Service
public class Service extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    private WebServiceTemplate template;

    public ProcessRequestTrans13Response getResponse(ProcessRequestTrans13 request){
        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
        String uri = "https://xxxxx.azure-api.net/?soapAction=https://secure.xxxxx.co.za/xxxx";

        return (ProcessRequestTrans13Response) template.marshalSendAndReceive(uri,request);
    }
    
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping
    public void test(@RequestBody ProcessRequestTrans13 requestTrans13) {

        ProcessRequestTrans13Response response = service.getResponse(requestTrans13);
    
    }
}
```

**Error**

```js
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Access Denied [401]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.dataone.backend.service.TransunionService.getResponse(TransunionService.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.dataone.backend.controllers.CompositeApiController.test(CompositeApiController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

This is an example of a post request that the API Manager gives:

```html
POST https://dataone-dev.azure-api.net/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dataone-dev.azure-api.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;action="https://secure.xxx.co.za/xxx"
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Body>
    <ProcessRequestTrans13 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://secure.xxx.co.za/xxx">
      <BureauEnquiry13>
        <ClientRequestID>ClientRequestID1</ClientRequestID>
        <SubscriberCode>SubscriberCode1</SubscriberCode>
        <ClientReference>ClientReference1</ClientReference>
        <BranchNumber>BranchNumber1</BranchNumber>
        <BatchNumber>BatchNumber1</BatchNumber>
        <SecurityCode>SecurityCode1</SecurityCode>
        <EnquirerContactName>EnquirerContactName1</EnquirerContactName>
        <EnquirerContactPhoneNo>EnquirerContactPhoneNo1</EnquirerContactPhoneNo>
        <EnquiryAmount>EnquiryAmount1</EnquiryAmount>
        <EnquiryType>EnquiryType1</EnquiryType>
        <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
        <Forename1>Forename11</Forename1>
        <Forename2>Forename21</Forename2>
        <Forename3>Forename31</Forename3>
        <MaidenName>MaidenName1</MaidenName>
        <BirthDate>BirthDate1</BirthDate>
        <IdentityNo1>IdentityNo11</IdentityNo1>
        <IdentityNo2>IdentityNo21</IdentityNo2>
        <Sex>Sex1</Sex>
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <MaritalStatus>MaritalStatus1</MaritalStatus>
        <NoOfDependants>NoOfDependants1</NoOfDependants>
        <AddressLine1>AddressLine11</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>AddressLine21</AddressLine2>
        <Suburb>Suburb1</Suburb>
        <City>City1</City>
        <PostalCode>PostalCode1</PostalCode>
        <ProvinceCode>ProvinceCode1</ProvinceCode>
        <Address1Period>Address1Period1</Address1Period>
        <OwnerTenant>OwnerTenant1</OwnerTenant>
        <HomeTelCode>HomeTelCode1</HomeTelCode>
        <HomeTelNo>HomeTelNo1</HomeTelNo>
        <WorkTelCode>WorkTelCode1</WorkTelCode>
        <WorkTelNo>WorkTelNo1</WorkTelNo>
        <SpouseForename1>SpouseForename11</SpouseForename1>
        <SpouseForename2>SpouseForename21</SpouseForename2>
        <Address2Line1>Address2Line11</Address2Line1>
        <Address2Line2>Address2Line21</Address2Line2>
        <Address2Suburb>Address2Suburb1</Address2Suburb>
        <Address2City>Address2City1</Address2City>
        <Address2PostalCode>Address2PostalCode1</Address2PostalCode>
        <Address2ProvinceCode>Address2ProvinceCode1</Address2ProvinceCode>
        <Address2Period>Address2Period1</Address2Period>
        <Occupation>Occupation1</Occupation>
        <Employer>Employer1</Employer>
        <EmploymentPeriod>EmploymentPeriod1</EmploymentPeriod>
        <Salary>Salary1</Salary>
        <BankName>BankName1</BankName>
        <BankBranch>BankBranch1</BankBranch>
        <BankBranchCode>BankBranchCode1</BankBranchCode>
        <BankAccountNumber>BankAccountNumber1</BankAccountNumber>
        <OperatorIdentity>OperatorIdentity1</OperatorIdentity>
        <ul_short_score>ul_short_score1</ul_short_score>
        <ul_medium_score>ul_medium_score1</ul_medium_score>
        <ul_long_score>ul_long_score1</ul_long_score>
        <ul_average_score>ul_average_score1</ul_average_score>
        <CellNo>CellNo1</CellNo>
        <EmailAddress>EmailAddress1</EmailAddress>
      </BureauEnquiry13>
    </ProcessRequestTrans13>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274378/add-soapheader-to-org-springframework-ws-webservicemessage might help

Comment: Thanks this worked. I followed the second answer and not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

[Add SoapHeader to org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274378/add-soapheader-to-org-springframework-ws-webservicemessage)

This worked for me. I followed the second solution and not the first one.